# Install XAMPP in Ubuntu NOT as root

Tags: ubuntu, xampp, filesystems, lamp

I've installed XAMPP and that worked fine. It was installed in **/opt/lampp/**.

But now I need to install it again (I uninstalled it) NOT as root.

**Important:** Typing `sudo` for every thing I do is not the problem, but a bunch of other issues related to permissions while developing.

Can I move/install XAMPP to another location to have the user privileges?

The installer does not seem to give me that option.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about moving Xampp somewhere else. However, if you are just interested in the lamp stack, you can follow instructions to install it as described [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP). The binaries for Apache, MySql and PHP will be installed somewhere else than /opt/lampp. And most likely, your default directory for your web content will be in /var/www.

However, you seem to have problems with permissions. Maybe you should give us a little more details about what kind of problems you have and what you would like to achieve. It could be that you just need to change the ownership of directories so that it would belong to a user.

Comment: I'l take a look to the LAMP stack. 

In example: I am developing a ProcessWire site locally (withint htdocs). When I change an image, then I refresh the page, said image won't load, because of permissions issues. Than I have to chmod 777 to the file in order to view it.

Comment: I would suggest to have a look at the permissions and ownerships of your files. You don't have to give rwx to all users... Try a to sue the command `sudo chown <user>:www-data <file>` replacing user and file by relevant names. Then you can chmod back to something like 660...